# How can I have nested routing with parameters as well as defined routes?

Tags: angular, typescript, parameters, routes

I have a case in which an entity can have a child which can have a child, and so on. All entities are of the same type

`Parent -> Child -> Grandchild -> Great Grandchild -> n generation`

I need to be able to view any of those generations. My current solution is as follows:

**Routing module**

```
...
{
  path: 'item/:itemId/child',
  children: [{
    path: '**',
    component: ChildComponent
  }]
}
...
```

**Child Component**

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.url.subscribe((segments: UrlSegment[]) => {
    // Looking for the last segment
    this.loadChild(segments[segments.length -1].path);
  }
}
```

**Real route**

```
http://localhost:4200/app/item/123/child/123_1/child/123_1_1/child/123_1_1_1
```

In this case I want to load child 123_1_1_1

The issue here is that I also want to be able to edit one of these children. However, appending "edit" to the URL is hard to catch because the current routing thinks that's just another child.

My question is two-fold:

1. Am I going about the nested routes in the right way?
2. How can I have nested routes and also allow for routes such as "edit"?

Comment: If this principle works for you, it seems fine? To do the edit part you could maybe use a queryParam instead? Append ?edit=true maybe? Or you can inject ‘edit’ earlier, something like item/:itemId/edit/child (make sure that path comes before the other one)...

Comment: This is a good thought, but in this case I still can't navigate to ```parent/child/child/child/edit```. I'd be resigned to using a modal or some *ngIf magic.